# How to keep two version of an android application in the same device

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Whenever I try to install the 2nd version, it says that it is going to replace all data from the previous version. I did the following things to avoid such situations:

1. app names are different so .apk file name is also different
2. package names are different

My app has a database. Do I need to have different database name for these two version ?

So, I would like to know, what I am doing wrong and what more should be done? I am using eclipse simulator at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a different package name, there is no other way.
I had 2 different versions of the same product (free & paid) and used: com.package.paid & com.package.free.

This means that nothing is shared between the 2 apps (DB included).

You can also use ANT scripts to build both apps from the same code base, I just changed it manually every time I needed to build a version.

Comment: I have used two different package name but it didn't serve my purpose.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, make sure the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml file is different.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have changed the package= in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I renamed the package and also rename it in the android manifest file... but then I saw that java source were not updated. I manually update the package name in all but still there were bug. Can anybody tell me a proper way to change package name in eclipse android project

Comment: Select the package node in the package explorer, then select Refactor->Rename.  This should bring up a Rename Package dialog.