# How to run an android app on a real device with same app installed earlier?

Tags: android

I am getting the following error :-
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!

I do not want to un install the previous app from my real device.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why don't you want to uninstall ? 
It happend always ? Even if you uninstall the application ?

Comment: change your package name and run it, it will create a new APK with R created in this new package.

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222302/android-multiple-custom-versions-of-the-same-app

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059416/how-to-keep-two-version-of-an-android-application-in-the-same-device

Comment: if you want to update an application, you need the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run the same application from the different PC then you get this error(Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.).
There is one way to avoid this issue is you can use same signature file.
If you use same signature file you can run the same application from the different PC.

Reference link [here](https://amsheer007.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/developing-same-app-on-two-different-computers/)